# Django - how to get Table that is connected to User?

Tags: django

I have a built-in table from Django, "Users". Every user is getting stored in there.

Now, I have created another table called "Questions" - Questions contains personal questions (fields) that every User on their own should answer.

They are connected OneToOne:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

So far it's working. I can create a Question object and then assign it to a user. But:

How can I query the fields of Question that is assigned to a user? **In the end I want to have a big HTML form that contains all these questions the user can answer.**

I have tried following:

```
questions = request.user.question.objects.get(user=user)
    context = {'questions':questions}
```

That does not work and results in `AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Question instances`.

I am stuck here and don't know how to do this. If anyone can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to have a related name in your field.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name='question',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
```

By this you don't have to filter to get user's question, You can do this just by `user.question`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I query the fields of Question that is assigned to a user?

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

> In the end I want to have a big HTML form that contains all these
>   questions the user can answer.

Your template can look like this

```
{% for question in questions %} 
    {{ question.field_to_display_1 }}
    {{ question.field_to_display_2 }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How do I get the fields of the object in the HTML via Jiinja then? {% for i in questions %} and then {{ i }} ?